# Running a Bash Script with arguments as a Qt resource

Tags: c++, bash, qt, qt-creator

Qt newbie here :).
I'm currently executing a bash script in Qt using the `popen` function to redirect the output to a textBrowser in my application. When I add the script to my project as a resource it does not seem to execute anymore? I use the `:/myScript.sh` syntax and then try to add my arguments as QStrings. 
Any advice will be appreciated!

```
FILE *in; 
char buff[512]; 
QString args = ":/myScript.sh" + <arguments>; 
QByteArray ba = args.toLatin1(); 
char *temp = ba.data(); 
if(!(in = popen(temp , "r")))
{ 
    exit(1);
}
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
{ 
    ui->txtConsole->append(buff); 
}
ui->progressBar->setValue(50); pclose(in);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, but I can't be sure without seeing your code.  Can you share the code that you are using to generate the popen call, the `:/myScript.sh` stuff, and the QString args?

Comment: `FILE *in;
        char buff[512];
        QString args = ":/myScript.sh" + <arguments>;
        QByteArray ba = args.toLatin1();
        char *temp = ba.data();
        if(!(in = popen(temp , "r"))){
            exit(1);
        }

        while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
            ui->txtConsole->append(buff);
        }

        pclose(in);`

Comment: Since you are apparently in a GUI program, you might want to consider using `QProcess` instead of `popen()` to run the program asynchronously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking `popen` with the Qt resource path format will not do what you expect.

You are effectively trying to invoke is this:

```
 popen(":/myScript.sh args", "r");
```

The `popen` function doesn't know anything about the Qt resource system nor the `:/` syntax.  It expects the first parameter to a path on disk that the operating system understands.

Two choices:

1. Just ship the myScript.sh file as a separate file and execute it directly. (What you observed as working before you tried to make the script a resource).  If you aren't using *compiled* resources, chances are it already is a disk file.  Just invoke popen on the absolute path to the file instead of with the `:/` syntax.
2. Write code to extract the myScript.sh text file from the resources and save it locally to disk.  Then invoke popen on that saved file.

Comment: Thanks. It works when myScript.sh is a separate file. I just thought it might be nice to include it as a resource so it doesn't have to be copied over each time :)

Comment: You can use `QFile::copy()` to copy from the resource file to an actual file, or use `QTemporaryFile::createNativeFile()`

Answer (score 0):

Its running script file as a qt resource. You add arguments maybe this run.

`QStringList arg("-c");
 QFile file(":/scriptFile.sh");
 arg << file.readAll();
 process->start("sh", arg);`